# Complex query in Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

in my method Java, 
I would like to pass as a parameter to my collection MongoDB a complex query like this one:

```
{"$or": [{"$and": [{"contextID": "AKKA"}, {"messageID": "PIPPO"}]},
         {"$and": [{"domain": "Niguarda"}, {"hostName": {"$ne": "hostServer"}}]}
        ]
}
```

The string that contains the query is variable and passed as parameter in query string.

I tried to pass the query as parameter to method criteria

```
(queryDB.criteria("
    {"$or": [
        {"$and": [{"contextID": "AKKA"}, {"messageID": "PIPPO"}]},
        {"$and": [{"domain": "Niguarda"}, {"hostName": {"$ne": "hostServer"}}]}]
    }"
)
```

but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it does not work". Does it error? If so what's the error. Does it not produce the result you expect? If not what's the difference.

Comment: The result is the same that I get with an empty query

Comment: Important: the criteria parameter is passed by a variable String.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do would be

```
Query q = dao.createQuery();
q.or(
 q.and(new Criteria[]{ dao.createQuery().filter("contextID").equal("AKKA"),
                       dao.createQuery().filter("messageID").equal("PIPPO") }),
 q.and(new Criteria[]{ dao.createQuery().filter("domain").equal("Niguarda"),
                       dao.createQuery().filter("hostname").notEqual("hostServer") })
);
```

Comment: Is impossible for me. The query is dynamic i.e. passed to code by parameter.

Comment: Can you edit the question to reflect this last comment you made? what's wrong with doing filter( dynamicParam ).equal( dynamicParam2 ) etc.?

Comment: The structure of the query is variable.

Comment: ... The query could be a simple query or a composite complex query (with $or, $and, $gte and so on...)

Comment: Do yoy know another way? Perhaps by using this code:String s = "{$query:{\"$and\":[{\"ipAddress\":\"10.100.203.120\"},{\"contexID\":\"AKKA\"}]}}";
          

             DBObject dbObjQuery = (DBObject) JSON.parse(s);
              
             
                 
             strOut = strOut.append(dbCollection.find(dbObjQuery).count());

Comment: You can programmatically make the query up as illustrated in the answer

Comment: Seems to me like you're using the native driver not morphia like uh you said in the title

Comment: The second try use the native driver. But the question is the same. There is a query unknown to submit. I don't know a priori the structure, the operators... I would like, in my method, to pass the query as it is received by the method without translate in code.

Comment: It is not important to use morphia or native driver. It's important avoid to translate in code.

Comment: What do you mean "translate in code"?  If you're worried about a performance problem, since Morphia uses the native Java driver, there is no performance implication in using morphia and the Java driver side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

This is now the code (it's works fine but I abandoned morphia):

```
public long count(String query) throws Exception {
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB(mongoDBName);
    DBCollection dbCollection = db.getCollection(mongoDBCollection);

    DBObject dbObjQuery;

    long l = 0;
    try {

        if (!(query == null)) {
            dbObjQuery = (DBObject) JSON.parse(query);
            l = dbCollection.find(dbObjQuery).count();
        } else {
            l = dbCollection.find().count();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {

    }

    return l;

}
```

There is another way to do this with morphia?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to create a dynamic query with Morphia, not without doing something like reflection.  However, if you showed the Java class of the object you're querying for, it might help us to find a solution.

Comment: You  didn't need to drop morphia, you can access the driver directly as well through morphia.